Did I understand the concept of Hypergeometric Random Variable correctly?
I am having some issues understanding the concept of a hypergeometric random variable. I was studying this concept from the book, "Introduction to Probability Models" by S Ross. The thing that was written there about this type of random variables goes somewhat like this:

Consider a collection of $N$ balls, some of which are white in color and the rest are black. In particular suppose that $Np$ of them are white and $N −Np$ are black, where $p$ is assumed to be unknown. We are interested in estimating $p,$ the fraction of the balls that are white, by randomly choosing and then determining the colors of $n$ balls in the collection. In such situations as described in the preceding, it is common to use the fraction of the sampled collection that white as an estimator of p. Hence, if we let $X_i=1,$ if the ith ball chosen is white and $X_i=0,$ otherwise for $i=1,2,3,...,n.$ Then the usual estimator of $p$ is $X=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i.$ Such a random variable $X$ is called hypergeometric random variable and has a probability mass function given by $P\{X=k\}=\frac{\binom{Np}{k}\binom{N-Np}{n-k}}{\binom{N}{n}}.$


Reading this, my understanding is:
Suppose we have a collection of $N$ balls of which, $W$ balls are white and the remaining $N-W$ balls are black. From these $N$ balls, we choose $n$ balls at random. If $X$ denotes the random variable that measures the total number of white balls present in this $n$ randomly chosen balls, then $X$ is called the hypergeometric random variable. Moreover, the probability mass function of $X$ is given by $p$ such that $p(k)=\binom{W}{k}\binom{N-W}{n-k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k},$ for $k=0,1,...,n$ and $p(k)=0,$ otherwise, where $p$ denotes the probability that a ball in the $n$ randomly chosen balls is white.
I want to know if my understanding is correct? Also, the probability mass function of $X$ that I calculated above, seems to work in the most general case. Is that evaluation correct? I am asking these clarifications because this concept is relatively new to me, and I am trying to know if got it all correct or not. If I made any mistake in my understanding of this concept, please do point it out. I seek to understand this concept with a complete clarity.

This is incorrect, since "the probability that a ball in the  randomly chosen balls is white" changes at each draw.

What you have done is replacing $Np$ by $W$; the 2 are exactly equal, so no harm done, but it does not chage anything. Then you replaced the denominator $\binom N n$, which does not depend on $k$ or $p$, by $p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$, which depends both on p, and k. So obviously the 2 formulas are not identical. Which might you guess is correct? For a hint, you may check wikipedia, for hypergeometric distribution.

Saying that the probability of seeing $k$ white balls from the $n$ sampled without replacement is $\frac{\binom{W}{k}\binom{N-W}{n-k}}{\binom{N}{n}}$ would be correct, at least for $0 \le k \le \min(n,W)$.
